# htaccess - Get error the page isn't redirecting properly

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm trying to redirect all requests except some file types to download.php with this .htaccess file.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !(\.php|\.html|\.css|\.jpeg|\.jpg\.png|\.js)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /download.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

I have  place this htaccess in root folder, i get error from both firefox and chrome "The page isn't redirecting properly". If i move the htaccess in some sub directory, works perfect. Please help...

Comment: Have you checked for any issues in your httpd.conf that might be disallowing .htaccess files in the root directory?

Answer (score 0):

try the next code.

```html
<Files ~ "^\.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options Indexes
DirectoryIndex download.php       
order deny,allow
deny from *.php
deny from *.html
deny from *.css
deny from *.jpeg
deny from *.jpg
deny from *.png
deny from *.js
```